# Remove the border glow on Kendo UI dropdowns and multiselect keeping bootstrap skin?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How can I remove the border glow on Kendo UI dropdowns and multiselect without removing the bootstrap skin?

These are the styles I´m loading:

```
@Html.StyleSheet(Url.WidgetContent("~/Mvc/Scripts/kendo/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common.min.css"), "top")
@Html.StyleSheet(Url.WidgetContent("~/Mvc/Scripts/kendo/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"), "top")
```

Comment: Check the elements in the DOM inspector to see what exactly is adding the glow. My guess would be a `box-shadow` or `outline`. Then you can override those styles to remove them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan box-shadow was the case. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please add as an answer to I can close and mark as correct.

Comment: Sure, I've added one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is most commonly created with either a `box-shadow` or `outline`. Check the elements in the DOM inspector and then override those styles to remove them.